# More questions on quantifiers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I have the  following questions:

Write the following statements in more abbreviated form, using quantifiers.
Here the short phrases “is prime” and “is a line” are allowed, and the
symbol $\Pi$ may be used for “the plane.”

(a) 17 is not the largest prime number.

**My Attempt: ($\exists x  \in \Bbb P ) (x > 17 )$**

(b) There is no largest prime number.

**My Attempt: $(\forall x  \in \Bbb P )(\exists y \in \Bbb P ) (x < y)$**

(c) Every real number has a fifth root.

**My Attempt: $(\forall x  \in \Bbb R )(\exists y \in \Bbb R ) (y^5 = x )$**

(d) Every pair of distinct points in the plane lies on a unique line.

I am still unsure about my attempts.  Could some confirm whether my attempts are correct or not and point me in the  right direction when it comes to part (d).

Comment: (a)-(c) are fine. But i would prefer, e.g. $(\exists x)(Prime(x) \land x > 17)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA and for (d)?

Comment: For (d) you have to state the existence condition for the two points, like : $(\forall x)(\forall y)[(x \in \Pi \land y \in \Pi \land x \ne y) \rightarrow (\exists ! l)(Line(l) \land x \in l \land y \in l)]$ assuming that you are allowed to use the "unique" symbol : $\exists !$.

Comment: Without that symbol, you can say something to the effect of, if the points are on the line $L$ and on the line $M$, then $L=M$.

Comment: For the "There is a unique $x$" symbol : $\exists !$, see page 51.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done very well on $(a) - (c)$. Your translations on those are entirely correct.

For (d): "Every pair of distinct points in the plane lies on a unique line."

$$(\forall x)\,(\forall y)\,[(x \in \Pi \,\land\, y \in \Pi\, \land\, x \ne y) \rightarrow (\exists ! \,\mathcal l)(Line(\mathcal l) \land x \in l \land y \in \mathcal l)]$$

Here, $\exists !$ denotes "There exists a unique".

If you haven't yet encountered this quantifier, we can still translate $(d)$ without it, though the statement becomes more elaborate:

$$(\forall x)\,(\forall y)\,[(x \in \Pi \,\land\, y \in \Pi\, \land\, x \ne y) \rightarrow (\exists \,\mathcal l)(Line(\mathcal l) \land x \in l \land y \in \mathcal l\land (\forall \mathcal l')(\mathcal l' \neq \mathcal l \rightarrow  (x \notin \mathcal l' \lor y \notin \mathcal l'))]$$